# Should it be "wouldn't" or "didn't"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> He promised he would come to the party. And I said I would be
>   disappointed if he **didn't / wouldn't**.

It seems like it's the second conditional, which means the right option is **didn't**. However, I took the phrase from an American sitcom where it was said with **wouldn't**. So I wonder whether the only correct option in this phrase is **didn't**, or maybe it's also acceptable to use **wouldn't** here.

Comment: "He promised he would come to the party. And I said I would be disappointed if he wouldn't" sounds just plain wrong to me. If you gave us a link to the episode, and a time stamp, we might be able to be more helpful. Note that sometimes characters in sitcoms speak a little sloppily.

Comment: "Didn't" would be disappointment after never appearing at the party. "Wouldn't" is disappointment during this conversation when he was invited and turned it down. It seemed straightforward I wrote that but another interpretation refers to the *promise* rather than the actual attendance. In that case you could probably use either one.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit tricky there...

At some point I'd say it is depending on the situation. **Didn't** could than be used as a more strict way to express yourself than **wouldn't**, because you could add "didn't come!" or "wouldn't consider coming." after those phrases.

On the other hand it would be pretty illogical to add another condition by using the second **would** in the sentence, because it would kind of mean that you would be sad, if he **wouldn't** come but wouldn't mind that much.

After all I'd say that (in context) **didn't** is more likely to be used instead of **wouldn't**.

Comment: "Unlogic" isn't a word. Do you mean "illogical"?

Comment: @Catija Yeah you're totally right... :>